# Setting different start and end timezone when creating new event in Calendar

Tags: macos, calendar, timezone

I'd like to create an event of my flight which is between two cities in different time zones on macOS. I know I can do it on iOS but can't make it work on mac.

Let's say my **departure (start)** is on **11:40 (CET)** and **arrival (end)** is at **14:20 (EET)**.

macOS (seems like there is one setting for both **start** and **end**):

[image]

iOS (separate timezone settings for **start** and **end**):

[image]

Comment: Even if you set your event on your iPhone, you will not see the options to edit on your Mac.